# Why I am still not getting this code done?

Tags: php

I already tried changing quotes, dots, but still getting a error. Can't find the mistake!

```
$Title .= '
        <meta property="og:description" content="<?php
  if ( function_exists('wpseo_get_value') ) {
    echo wpseo_get_value('metadesc');
  } else {
    echo $post->post_excerpt;
  }
?>"/>
    ';
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, *include it in your question*. Always include that sort of information in your question.

Comment: If you expect those variables inside to be evaluated, then you should probably do that before declaring the entire thing as a literal value.

Answer (score 2):

you get an error because you are not escaping your quotes among other things.
What you need is:

```
$Title .= '<meta property="og:description" content="';
if ( function_exists('wpseo_get_value') ) {
    $Title .= wpseo_get_value('metadesc');
} else {
    $Title .= $post->post_excerpt;
}
$Title .= '"/>';
```